# How can I insert records from one table into second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, unpivot

The current table is not setup for growth and I'd like to migrate the existing data to a table better suited for expansion.  Let me explain:

The current table is set like:

```
+--------+---------------+----+----+----+------+-----------+
|     id | DateOfService | AM | MD | PM | RATE | CLIENT_ID |
+--------+---------------+----+----+----+------+-----------+
|      1 | 3/4/2013      |  1 |  0 |  0 |   10 |       123 |
|      2 | 3/5/2013      |  1 |  0 |  0 |   10 |       123 |
|      3 | 3/6/2013      |  1 |  0 |  0 |   10 |       123 |
|      4 | 3/5/2013      |  0 |  1 |  1 |   50 |       147 |
|      5 | 3/6/2013      |  1 |  1 |  1 |   25 |       189 |
+--------+---------------+----+----+----+------+-----------+
```

And instead, I want to setup my table like:

```
+----------+---------------+---------------+-----------+
|     pkid | DateOfService | ServiceTypeID | CLIENT_ID |
+----------+---------------+---------------+-----------+
|        1 | 3/4/2013      |             1 |       123 |
|        2 | 3/5/2013      |             1 |       123 |
|        3 | 3/6/2013      |             1 |       123 |
|        4 | 3/5/2013      |             2 |       147 |
|        5 | 3/5/2013      |             3 |       147 |
|        6 | 3/6/2013      |             1 |       189 |
|        7 | 3/6/2013      |             2 |       189 |
|        8 | 3/6/2013      |             3 |       189 |
+----------+---------------+---------------+-----------+
```

The ServiceTypeID table would be an `options` table setup something like:

```
+-------------------+---------+
|     ServiceTypeID | Service |
+-------------------+---------+
|                 1 | AM      |
|                 2 | MD      |
|                 3 | PM      |
+-------------------+---------+
```

I need help coming up with a query I can run that will select and loop over the existing data and populate my new table.

Comment: I don't understand where pkid is coming from

Comment: @hogan You misunderstanding makes sense.  I didn't type the numerical values correctly.  Thanks for catching that.  I've updated the example pkid values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your options table is "setup", something like this would work:

```
INSERT INTO newtable
  SELECT id, dateofservice, 1, clientid
  FROM oldTable
  WHERE AM = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, dateofservice, 2, clientid
  FROM oldTable
  WHERE MD = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, dateofservice, 3, clientid
  FROM oldTable
  WHERE PM = 1
```

NB, I'm making the same assumption blue is, your example table is wrong and pk should have had the values 1,2,3,4,4,5,5,5

If you want that key to be unique then just define it as an auto increment key and don't include it in this select.

Comment: Thanks Hogan, the idea you presented here was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`UNPIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function to turn your current table from columns into rows. Then you can join on your `options` table and insert the data into your new table.

The `UNPIVOT` code will be:

```
select id,
  dateofservice,
  client_id,
  col, 
  value
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in (AM, MD, PM)
) unpiv
where value <> 0
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6cb1c/4)

Then you will join to your `options` table to get the result. You can use this query to `INSERT INTO` your new table:

```
-- INSERT INTO yourNewTable
select src.id as pkid,
  src.dateofservice,
  o.servicetypeid,
  src.client_id
from
(
  select id,
    dateofservice,
    client_id,
    col, 
    value
  from yourtable
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (AM, MD, PM)
  ) unpiv
  where value <> 0
) src
inner join options o
  on src.col = o.service
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6cb1c/3)

Comment: This seems to be a trend, I put a simple solution that approaches the answer and you put an exact complex one.  Next, over time everyone tell me mine is wrong.  :)   Have a good night blue.

Comment: @Hogan I don't see anything wrong with your solution. I just prefer using `pivot` and `unpivot` to solve things (you will see that in my profile). I also used a join to let the code get the `servicetypeid` instead of hard-coding them to prevent fat-finger typing errors.  `:)`

Comment: @bluefeet I love the example you provided but I may be too green to work with pivot and unpivot (never even heard of unpivot before).  BUT the SQL Fiddle is excellent!  I'll definitely try it though.